# Splitting line based on comma, strange line

Tags: java, regex

I have the following line comma separated,

`LanguageID=0,LastKnownPeriod="Active",c_MultiPartyCall={Counter=1,TimeStamp=1394539271448},LTH={Data=["1|MTC|01.01.1970 15:00:00|0.0|7|-1|OnPeakAccountID|0|1000||","1|MTC|01.01.1970 15:00:00|0.0|7|-1|OnPeakAccountID|0|1000||"}`

Using split method, I can get comma seperated values but the actual problem comes when the text `c_MultiPartyCall={Counter=1,TimeStamp=1394539271448}`, since comma is found within itself.

so the word after splitting should be,

- `LanguageID=0`
- `LastKnownPeriod="Active"`
- `c_MultiPartyCall={Counter=1,TimeStamp=1394539271448}` (comma is again found within the word)
- `LTH={Data=["1|MTC|01.01.1970 15:00:00|0.0|7|-1|OnPeakAccountID|0|1000||","1|MTC|01.01.1970 15:00:00|0.0|7|-1|OnPeakAccountID|0|1000||"}` (comma is again found within the word in curly brackets)

I tried with following code but didn't work:

```
String arr[]=input_line.split("(.*!{),(.*!})");
for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    System.out.println(arr[i]);
```

Please advise.

Comment: Look at the related questions on the right.  You'd find examples of split on a delimiter except within ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regular expressions instead:

```
([\w_]+=(?:\{[\w=_,\[\]"\|:\.\s-]*\}))|([^,]+)
```

This will group the line into 4 sections:

- LanguageID=0
- LastKnownPeriod="Active"
- c_MultiPartyCall={Counter=1,TimeStamp=1394539271448}
- LTH={Data=["1|MTC|01.01.1970 15:00:00|0.0|7|-1|OnPeakAccountID|0|1000||","1|MTC|01.01.1970 15:00:00|0.0|7|-1|OnPeakAccountID|0|1000||"}

Code:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class JavaRegEx {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String line = "LanguageID=0,LastKnownPeriod=\"Active\",c_MultiPartyCall={Counter=1,TimeStamp=1394539271448},LTH={Data=[\"1|MTC|01.01.1970 15:00:00|0.0|7|-1|OnPeakAccountID|0|1000||\",\"1|MTC|01.01.1970 15:00:00|0.0|7|-1|OnPeakAccountID|0|1000||\"}";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([\\w_]+=(?:\\{[\\w=_,\\[\\]\"\\|:\\.\\s-]*\\}))|([^,]+)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);

    while(matcher.find())
        System.out.println(matcher.group(0));

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, just splitting on a comma isn't how CSV works

```
a,b,"c,d"
```

has only three values, `a`, `b`, and `c,d`. I recommend using a CSV parser, like [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/). CSV is not terribly complicated, but it isn't as simple as split by comma.

---

Second, your CSV data is invalid because you have a quote and a comma in a field that isn't quoted.

In othe words, if you want the values `a`, `b","c`, then the CSV is

```
a,"b"",""c"
```

(Note that quotes are double-escaped.)

Otherwise, it is impossible to tell what fields you actually wanted. A CSV parser would choke on your data.

Answer (score 1):

While it might be possible to do this by `split()`, it's much easier to match the actual tokens (where `split()` matches the delimiters *between* the tokens).  Your tokens all  consist of one or more of any characters other than comma or brace, optionally followed by a pair of braces enclosing some non-brace characters (which can include commas):

```
[^,{}]+(?:\{[^{}]+\})?
```

The Java code for that would be:

```
List<String> matchList = new ArrayList<String>();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^,{}]+(?:\\{[^{}]+\\})?");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    matchList.add(m.group());
}
```

But it looks like you can break it down further:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)=([^,{}]+|\\{[^{}]+\\})");
Matcher m = p.matcher(TEST_STR);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.printf("%nname = %s%nvalue = %s%n",
                      m.group(1), m.group(2));
}
```

output:

```
name = LanguageID
value = 0

name = LastKnownPeriod
value = "Active"

name = c_MultiPartyCall
value = {Counter=1,TimeStamp=1394539271448}

name = LTH
value = {Data=["1|MTC|01.01.1970 15:00:00|0.0|7|-1|OnPeakAccountID|0|1000||","1|MTC|01.01.1970 15:00:00|0.0|7|-1|OnPeakA
ccountID|0|1000||"}
```